# load_model error: ValueError: Improperly formatted model config when tensorflow.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, inference

I can load the model with load_model("model.h5") in colab and do a model.predict which works. But when I download the h5 file and run load_model locally, the load_model call gets an error "ValueError: Improperly formatted model config."

This is the model:

```
base_model=MobileNet(weights='imagenet',include_top=False) #imports the mobilenet model and discards the last 1000 neuron layer.

x=base_model.output
x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x=Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x) #we add dense layers so that the model can learn more complex functions and classify for better results.
x=Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 2
x=Dense(512,activation='relu')(x) #dense layer 3
preds=Dense(2,activation='softmax')(x) #final layer with softmax activation
```

using transfer learning

```
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=preds)

for layer in model.layers[:20]:
    layer.trainable=False
for layer in model.layers[20:]:
    layer.trainable=True
```

then trained

```
train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/content/chest_xray/train/',
                                                  target_size=(224,224),
                                                  color_mode='rgb',
                                                  batch_size=32,
                                                  class_mode='categorical', shuffle=True)


model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
# Adam optimizer
# loss function will be categorical cross entropy
# evaluation metric will be accuracy

step_size_train=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                   steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
                   epochs=5)
```

model saved

```
model.save('chest-xray-pneumonia.h5')
```

prediction works

```
ill_path = "/content/chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA/" 
good_path = "/content/chest_xray/train/NORMAL/" 

ill_pic = ill_path + os.listdir(ill_path)[1]
good_pic = good_path + os.listdir(good_path)[1]

print(get_rez(ill_pic))
print(get_rez(good_pic))
```

But locally running in a Flask app python script main.py, it doesn't

```
from flask import render_template, jsonify, Flask, redirect, url_for, request
from app import app
import random
import os
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
import ipdb

weightsPath = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
```

get error on the next line: ValueError: Improperly formatted model config.

```
 new_model = load_model(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],"chest-xray-pneumonia.h5"))

def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f.filename)
      #f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f.filename))
      ill_pic = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
      f.filename)

print(get_rez(ill_pic))
```

Comment: Are you mixing keras and tf.keras? Because these aren't compatible with each other.

Comment: I think the mistake comes from using different versions of keras, at least that's the mistake I've had to face. Try updating keras on both sides and it might be fixed.

Comment: Both colab and local have Keras 2.2.4 and tensorflow 1.13.1, so it's not that. Also not using keras, only tensorflow.keras, at least I am only importing tensorflow.keras.
Any other ideas gratefully received.